# ShareKit 2.0 iOS 5.1 Logging in progress bar never disappear

Tags: ios, sharekit

I use ShareKit for integration few network services. Facebook works good for iOS 6.0 but does not work for iOS 5.1.

This is my method below to push message to Facebook:

```
- (void)openFacebook:(id)sender {    
    SHKItem *post = [SHKItem text: @"Share this text"];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:post];
}
```

I alos configured url scheme and `-facebookAppId:` method. Maybe I something miss.

Do I need add handleOpenURL method or some other?